# Writing binary files in QT and reading in matlab

Tags: qt, matlab, file-io, binary, binaryfiles

Trying to do the simplest thing ever. Write a number in QT in binary mode (unsigned 16) and read the file in matlab. I use Append mode since I will be adding numbers to the file in the future But can't seem to do this right.

This is the QT code:

```
QFile f("C:\\temp.dat");
f.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append)
QDataStream out(&f);
out<<quint16(270);
f.close();
```

And this is the Matlab code:

```
fid = fopen('C:\\temp.dat');
F_nums = fread(fid,1,'*uint16');
fclose(fid);
```

Seems very simple but it reads the numbers wrongly...

Thank you!

Comment: Wrongly is a bit vague. Have you looked at the file with a hex editor? First make sure the correct values are stored in the file. If this works start debugging your Matlab code.

Comment: Output: 3585, instead of: 270

Comment: This is not helpful, what output is that, who outputs it? Again, check the files content first...

Comment: Bytes are swapped. 3585=0xE01, 270=0x10E

Comment: The content of the files are correct for number up to 255. After that it show them wrongly. Roku, you are right! Thanks! Any idea why QT does that?

Comment: QDataStream's default byte order just is big endian. You can change it by using setByteOrder()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is really simple: you are writing big-endian data (MSB comes first), but Matlab by default expects little endian data. The fix is simple:

```
QFile f("C:\\temp.dat");
f.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append)
QDataStream out(&f);
out.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian); // *** set little endian byte order
out<<quint16(270);
f.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

`QDataStream` is not really meant to create streams that are portable across different applications. (It is meant to be portable across different OS and Qt versions, but always consumed by Qt.) The format is not guaranteed to be stable, so it could work today but break tomorrow. From the docs:

> QDataStream's binary format has evolved since Qt 1.0, and is likely to
>   continue evolving to reflect changes done in Qt. When inputting or
>   outputting complex types, it's very important to make sure that the
>   same version of the stream (version()) is used for reading and
>   writing.

If you want to share data, use an output format that is intended for sharing, like XML, Json, or, in a simple case like this, just write out the number as a ANSI string to a text file. Just substitute `QTextStream` for `QDataStream`.

Comment: Thanks Dave! The problem with text is that I have to write into the file many times with lot's of numbers. Writing simple text just takes a lot of CPU power and that's why binary files are considered.

Comment: Yeah, I understand, but there's no "correct" way to encode numbers in binary format. Qt arbitrarily chooses a format so that it can be used across various operating systems regardless of byte order, etc. But there's no guarantee that (a) your consuming (non-Qt) application agrees that this is the correct way, and (b) that Qt isn't going to decide to change the format in the next version. You can explicitly demand Qt use a certain version to get around problem (b), but Matlab may read binary numbers differently on a different OS.

Comment: Thank you so much, now it makes sense. It seems like the way around it is to make a QT exe that will read the binary file and convert it into txt at the end.

Comment: Dave: it is ridiculous to suggest that Qt "arbitrarily chooses a format". Not in the slightest. `QDataStream` has always used direct encoding of integer and floating point values, and it is *the way* to access binary format data in a portable fashion. The poster simply did not select correct endianness for the file. The "evolving" binary format refers to how Qt's own data structures are encoded. Integers are pretty much guaranteed to stay the way they are, it'd make not much sense otherwise. E.g.: I use QDataStream to portably read big-endian 32 bit floats coming in over the network.